# R - How to find the environment where a function is called from inside the called function?

Tags: r, scope

I'm trying to create a function that references the scope from which it was called to create a unique ID:

```
uniqueid <- function(name, envir = NULL) {

  if(identical(envir, globalenv())) {
    e = envir
  } else if (is.null(envir)) {
    e = parent.frame()
  } else if (is.environment(envir)) {
    e = envir
  } else {
    stop("given non-default argument \'envir\' is not an environment")
  }

  return(paste(sep = "",
    sub('<environment: (.*)>', '\\1', capture.output(e)),
    ".",
    name
    )
  )
}
```

What can I do to make this work the way I think it should work? R keeps returning the scope in which the function was defined, and not where it is evaluated:

```
hello <- new.env()
hello$env <- new.env()

eval(envir=hello$env, {
  print(environment())
  print(hello$env) #hello$env is an environment
  print(hello) #hello is an environment
  uniqueid('hi')
})
```

I'm trying to get at least one of these to match up, but it doesn't seem like it wants to work. R either returns the global environment, or the ever-changing scope of a temporary frame/environment created for an instance of a call to the function. The ID needs to be reproducible between multiple calls and dependent on the environment.

I know I could pass the environment, but I'm beginning to wonder whether doing capture of the caller's environment is actually possible.

Comment: What's `hello`? Is it `hello <- new.env(); hello$env <- new.env()` ?

Comment: @mathematical.coffee Both! I tried nesting environments to see if it was a problem with how many environments there were, but it has nothing to do with that.

Comment: Your example is not reproducible - cannot create `hello`, and `parent.frame` takes `n` as an argument, not an environment, or you get an error.

Comment: @mathematical.coffee I added more code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL,DR: `parent.frame()` not `parent.frame(environment())`; `evalq` not `eval`.

`parent.frame` takes argument `n` being number of generations to go back, not the result of an `environment()` call (which is an environment). If you leave it out of the `parent.frame()` call you're fine.

Also, yoru example code doesn't work as you expect, because your `environment()` command is being evaluated in the call to `eval`, before being evaluated *as part of* `eval`. I.e. you must quote your argument to `eval`. Alternatively, use `evalq` rather than `eval`.

E.g.

```
uniqueid <- function(name) {
  print(parent.frame())
}
hello <- new.env()
hello$env <- new.env()
evalq(envir=hello$env, {
  print(environment()) # prints hello$env
  print(hello$env)     # prints hello$env
  print(hello)         # prints hello
  uniqueid('hi')       # prints hello$env
})
```

E.g. this will get the environment ID and add it to the `name`:

```
uniqueid <- function(name) {
    # GlobalEnv etc have names; hello doesn't
    envName <- environmentName(parent.frame())
    # get the environment ID from the parent.frame() output if no name
    if (envName == "") {
        p <- parent.frame()
        envName <- sub('<environment: (.*)>', '\\1', capture.output(p))
    }
    return(paste(envName, name, sep=':'))
}
uniqueid('x') # R_GlobalEnv:x
print(hello) # <environment: 0x4641fa0>
evalq(envir=hello, uniqueid('x')) # "0x4641fa0:x"
print(hello$env) # <environment: 0x4640e60>
evalq(envir=hello$env, uniqueid('x')) # "0x4640e60:x"
```

Comment: I think the key thing here is that I didn't understand that the expression was being evaluated before it was inserted into the scope. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that `eval()` expects something that is unevaluated. By passing in a code block `{}`, you are not preventing evaluation. For example, consider the simpler case

```
a<-10
ee<-new.env()
ee$a<-5

eval(envir=ee, a)
# [1] 10
eval(envir=ee, {a})
# [1] 10
eval(envir=ee, quote(a))
# [1] 5
evalq(envir=ee, a)
# [1] 5
```

Notice how the last two either explicitly quote the expression, or use `evalq()` to do the quoting of the expression. These allow the evaluation to be delayed until executed inside the requested environment.

So if you just change your `eval()` to `evalq()`, you should be fine.