# Shiny - Why does Shiny not react to the result of an evaluated/parsed expression?

Tags: r, scope, shiny

Please refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31529049/r-how-to-find-the-environment-where-a-function-is-called-from-inside-the-calle) for some of the functions and context.

[image: Here's an overview of the app.]
[image: Some of the console output and debugging output is shown here.]

#### The Code

Right now, I'm trying to "cure" this server code:

```
env = module_env$normalization

eval(envir= module_env$normalization, {

jjjj <- reactive({
  eval(parse(text=paste(sep='', "input$", mod_id('var_echo'))))
})

####
#### vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
####
observeEvent(jjjj, {
# observeEvent(evalq(parse(text=paste(sep='', 'input$', mod_id('var_echo', env)))), {
  print("HEY")
  print(get('sum_exp', env))
})
####
#### ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
####

observeEvent(input$print_mod_id, {
  browser()

  print(mod_id('var_echo', env))
  print(paste("input$", mod_id('var_echo', env), sep=''))
  print(parse(text=paste(sep='', "input$", mod_id('var_echo', env))))
  print(eval(parse(text=paste(sep='', "input$", mod_id('var_echo', env)))))
})

})
```

which is meant to be paired with this UI code:

```
module_env$normalization <- new.env()
env = module_env$normalization

evalq(envir = env, {
  #Create the UI here
  ui_normalization <-
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel('Normalization (FPKM)',
      p("normalization"),
      actionButton(inputId = mod_id('var_echo', env), "Echo variables"),
      actionButton("print_mod_id", "Print module UI")
    )
  )

  print(mod_id('var_echo', env))

  #Create your initial input/output variables here
  sum_exp <- NULL
  output_sum_exp <- NULL

  #Always register last
  register_module(
    name="Normalization (FPKM)",
    module=ui_normalization,
    env=env,
    inputs=c('sum_exp'),
    outputs=c('output_sum_exp')
  )
})
```

These two files will be called at separate times during the app, but ultimately, will be called using `source("FILENAME.R", local=TRUE)` to localize the environment of the source file to the global environment, which also holds the app.

---

#### The Problem

Most of this is for debugging, but the most important thing is that the expression `jjjj` is being read by Shiny (the app does run), but doesn't react to when the button is pressed.

`mod_id()` is a special function designed to react to the environment that it is called from to generate a special key based on a string and its calling environment:

```
###Sample results for the print_mod_id print statements

[1] "id0x000000001e9047f0__var_echo"
[1] "input$id0x000000001e9047f0__var_echo"
expression(input$id0x000000001e9047f0__var_echo)
[1] 2
attr(,"class")
[1] "integer"                "shinyActionButtonValue"
```

Here's `mod_id(string, environment)`, which returns a string:

```
mod_id <- function(name, envir = NULL) {
  if(identical(envir, globalenv())) {
    e = envir
  } else if (is.null(envir)) {
    e = parent.frame()
  } else if (is.environment(envir)) {
    e = envir
  } else {
    stop("given non-default argument \'envir\' is not an environment")
  }
  return(paste(sep = "",
    "id",
    sub('<environment: (.*)>', '\\1', capture.output(e)),
    "__",
    name
    )
  )
}
```

#### Testing Observations

Here's some of the tests I've done:

1. The unique IDs generated by `mod_id()` for the UI and server are indeed the same. I've already gone in and fixed any discrepancies, so they do match up.
2. The expression used to get the final `input$INPUT_ID_FOR_SHINY` name works in another case, except when the variable name is substituted with the function `mod_id()`. I'm not exactly sure why, but it might have to do with the evaluation order caused by the overarching `eval` statement.
3. The event triggered by `jjjj` is triggered once at the beginning of the app. I have no idea why this happens, but the fact is that it does.

**Edit:** Additional testing, now have the Shiny source code on my machine. The expression is now: `evalq(as.name(paste(sep='', 'input$', mod_id('var_echo', env))))` but it still doesn't work.

Comment: What if you take off `eval()` and just leave `parse()` and maybe an explicit `quoted =TRUE` in the `reactive()` call. When you evaluate the call, there's not really a variable to watch any more, just a value.

Comment: @MrFlick Nope, nothing.

Comment: Are you using `observeEvent(jjjj, { ...` in your code or the commented-out version below? The current form that runs in your example won't work because the reactive expression `jjjj` needs to be evaluated using `jjjj()` in order for changes to trigger the observer.

Comment: @MikkoM That doesn't matter either.

Comment: Update: I still haven't solved this problem. I don't think I'll take a look at it until much later.